# People who don't broadcast their IP address?

Tags: privacy

At https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/9807/5228 Tom van der Woerdt wrote "people who don't broadcast their IP address".

What did he mean by that? Is there a way to set up a particular Bitcoin client so that it does not broadcast my IP address or to make it more private in other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Install [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) and add `tor=1` to your [bitcoin.conf](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11190/where-is-the-config-file-of-bitcoin-qt-kept/11210#11210).

Comment: But is that what Tom van der Woerdt meant?

Comment: Tor is the easiest and most effective way of protecting your IP address.

Comment: It's not very effective. It's slow as hell.

Comment: @InqierX You mean efficient? You can use a VPN, it will probably be faster.